# Set value of root XElement without affecting child elements

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

UPDATED: I still have this problem, better explanation.

I have a list of XElements and I'm iterating through them to check if it match a regex pattern. If there's a match, I need to replace the value of the current element without affecting his child elements.

For example,

```
<root>{REGEX:@Here}<child>Element</child> more content</root
```

In that case, I need to replace {REGEX:@Here} which is under the root element but his not a child element! If Use:

```
string newValue = xElement.ToString();
if(ReplaceRegex(ref newValue))
   xElement.ReplaceAll(newValue);
```

I'm losing the child elements and the tags get converted to & lt;child & gt;element in the value.
If I use:

```
xElement.SetValue(newValue);
```

The value of the xElement will be,

```
"{REGEX:Replaced} Element more content"
```

thus losing child elements as well.

What can I do to replace the value that will keep the child elements and work if the regex pattern is under the root element or child elements.

PS: I will add the regex function here for understanding purpose

```
    private bool ReplaceRegex(ref string text)
    {
        bool match = false;
        Regex linkRegex = new Regex(@"\{XPath:.*?\}", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);

        Match m = linkRegex.Match(text);

        while (m.Success)
        {
            match = true;
            string substring = m.Value;
            string xpath = substring.Replace("{XPath:", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);

            object temp = this.Container.Data.XPathEvaluate(xpath);

            text = text.Replace(substring, Utility.XPathResultToString(temp));

            m = m.NextMatch();
        }
        return match;
    }
```

Comment: `Value` just returns the concatenated text elements.  Do you need the regular expression to run on the entire content, or would running it on the individual text elements suffice?

Comment: I need it to run on the entire content

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck.  You're basically saying you want to take some content, strip out the child tags, run a regular expression on that, and then put the tags back into the result. But where would those tags go?

Comment: Hmm I'm not to sure if you get the problem. I need to iterate through all the elements(one way or another), get the value of each element, run the expression and if there's a match I replace the value. There's no need to strip out the tags to run the expression, maybe I should use toString?

Comment: If you have `<Root>This is <b>mixed</b> content</Root>` then the value of the Root node is `This is mixed content`.  If you want the regular expression to run against the entire string you'll loose the `<b>` tag.  On the other hand you can just iterate through the children and only run the regular expression on the Text Nodes "This is ", "mixed", and " content".

Comment: Yep, the expression run fine and the new content of the root element his copied in the string value. but how I can set the content of the root element without losing the tags? <Root>This is replaced <b>mixed</b> content </Root>

Comment: Are you sure the third last line `if(this.ReplaceRegex(ref value))` is correct? Shouldn't it make call to some other function rather than ReplaceRegex?

Comment: Yes it is, The ReplaceRegex(ref value) is another function with a different parameter not included in the code above.

Comment: In that case aren't you simply missing an `else`?

Comment: I guess you want to apply that function `ReplaceRegex(ref value)` on the **leaf** nodes (elements which don't have any child elements i.e. HasElements=false) and not on the **non-leaf** nodes (i.e. elements which have child elements). Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void ReplaceRegex(XElement xElement)
{
    if(xElement.HasElements)
    {
        foreach (XElement subElement in xElement.Elements())
            this.ReplaceRegex(subElement);
    }
    foreach(var node in xElement.Nodes().OfType<XText>())
    {
        string value = node.Value;
        if(this.ReplaceRegex(ref value))
            node.Value = value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Regarding your mixed-content comment, edited the code to take care of text nodes. See if it works.

Comment: This would work if the pattern is matched only in sub elements, but my root element has mixed content. <Root>Some value <child> value </child> </Root> , in that case the value of child element get replaced but not the root element.